# Multimap implementation with duplicate keys

Tags: java, multimap

I have a function which returns an array list in the following way

```
[java.lang.String=name, int=parameters, byte=paramOne, java.lang.String=format, byte=paramTwo]
```

and is stored in a variable like : `List<Entry<String, String>> dataTypes`

Now I want to make a map that stores the key-value pairs like this list. I have tried to make separate lists of keys and values and I'm trying to use a multimap to map it against each other but it does not work. (I know hashmaps can't store duplicate keys and will just take the last duplicate key with its respective value, that's why I'm trying to use multimaps)
This is the code I'm trying:

```
        List<String> dataTypeValues = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> dataTypeKeysList = new ArrayList<>();
        String keyString = null;
        String valueString = null;
                            
        for(Entry<String, String> dt : dataTypes) {
            dataTypeKeys.add(dt.getKey());
            keyString = dataTypeKeys.toString();
            
        }
        for(Entry<String, String> dt : dataTypes) {
            dataTypeValues.add(dt.getValue());
            valueString = dataTypeValues.toString();
        }
        Multimap<String, String> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();         
        multiMap.put(keyString, valueString);
        System.out.println(multiMap);
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
{[java.lang.String, int, byte, java.lang.String, byte]=[[name, parameters, paramOne, format, paramTwo]]}
```

And this is the output I'm trying to get:

```
{java.lang.String=[name], int=[parameters], byte=[paramOne,paramTwo], java.lang.String=[format]}
```

Any advice would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** : The answers provided by **@User - Upvote don't say Thanks** and **@Louis Wasserman** works perfectly. I accepted the answer from **@User - Upvote don't say Thanks** because of the discussion. If I could I would accept both these answers.
Thank you

Comment: Hey, based on your activity, it seems you've a habit of not accepting an answer to the questions you ask. People *voluntarily* help others here, the least you can do is show some appreciation by accepting an answer.

Comment: Your current data structure is perfect for your expected output  I think `List<Entry<String, String>`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks

Comment: For the accepted answer you can't get the expected output you mention in question. Your current data structure is perfect for store duplicate key data with value. I don't understand why you want to use multimap

Comment: Yes the existing DS stores it perfectly but it comes from the function which returns an ArrayList and has to be stored in that particular way. I need to use a proper map so that I can access functions like keySet() or values(). In the current scenario, I can not do so. @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks

Comment: Then how can you know for `byte` which value should return `paramOne` or `paramTwo`  from map? and you can get keys and values in one-liner using steam API from ArrayList

Comment: `byte` should have both the values so that later I can check if it is mapped to one of these values or both. I was trying to make the map as:  `Multimap<String, List<String>> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create(); ` so that a key can have a list of values. @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks

Comment: Then update your question's expected output so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupingBy` which is the ideal case for you I think

```
Map<String, List<String>> res =
                dataTypes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                             Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 1):

> take the last duplicate key

That is the exact purpose of [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)).

```
Map<String, list<String> multiMap = dataTypes.stream.collect(toMap(
  Map.Entry::getKey,
  e -> singletonList(e.getValue()),
  (v1, v2) -> {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.addAll(v1);
    values.addAll(v2);

    return values;
  }
))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why you're trying to put the entries into the multimap like that.  At minimum, what you want is

```
for (Entry<String, String> dt : dataTypes) {
  multiMap.put(dt.getKey(), dt.getValue());
}
```

Then, you probably want to print `multimap.entries()`.  And if you care about the order of the entries, you probably want `LinkedListMultimap`.